# Multiple Column Duplicate in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with fields (id , gid, uid)
For some rows (gid, uid) are same. There is duplicate.

Example 1:(repeated)

```
id      gid     uid

5802    1032    1247

5806    1032    1247

5807    1032    1247

5808    1032    1247
```

Example 2: (occurs once)

```
id      gid     uid

5103    1132    1290
```

In my case I want to pass uid and gid and check if there are duplicates 
- Return True if (gid,uid) doesnot occur in the table 
- Otherwise it return false.( for Example 1 and Example 2 )

I tried this query to return true or false.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS  (SELECT A.*
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN (SELECT gid, uid
            FROM table1
            GROUP BY gid, uid
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 0) 
ON A.gid = '1011' AND A.uid = '1086') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END from dual;
```

But it always returns True ; Please help in solving the same

Comment: provide your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: Hardcoded id's are usually a very bad idea.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I am not hardcoding , It is for illustrative purpose only . Thanks @Jarlh

Comment: My output should be either True or False @zealous

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result. It's far from clear what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) = 1 THEN 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' END FROM YOUR_tABLE
WHERE gid = '1011' AND uid = '1086'
```

Comment: Please note that You need to handle the scenario when there is no matching `gid` and `uid` present in the table. `count(1)` will return `0` in that case and the query will return `false`. so handle it according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the instant help... SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(1) = 0 THEN 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' END FROM t1
WHERE gid IN (Select id from t2 where name ='E&R Anayst')   AND uid IN  (Select id from t3 where external_id = '898989');  I have to return True if it doesnt occur and if it occurs once or more I have to return false . This is my exact scenraio.... The above queries work well but when I give a name which has & sign in it it asks for a substitution variable otherwise it works fine , Any thoughts on it ?  @Tejash

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    gid
    ,uid
,case when [count]>1 then 'False' else 'True' end Result
from (
    select 
    gid
    ,uid
    ,count(*) [count]
    from Table1 
    group by 
    gid
    ,uid
) temp
```

[image: Result]